# Error java.lang.NullPointerException on method getReadableDatabase()

Tags: android, sqlite, listpreference

Could you please help me with error "java.lang.NullPointerException". I use custom listpreference to show elements from database. There two files CustomListPreference.java and DbHelper.java

CustomListPreference.java

```
public class CustomListPreference extends ListPreference {
    CustomListPreferenceAdapter customListPreferenceAdapter = null;
    Context mContext;

private SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper dbHelp = new DbHelper(mContext);

public CustomListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder)
{

    ...

    try {
    db = dbHelp.getReadableDatabase();//I get error java.lang.NullPointerException
  ...
}
```

DbHelper.java

```
   import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="myBase";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("create table tUser ("
              + "id integer primary key autoincrement," 
              + "name text,"
              + "exists integer" + ");");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

Comment: The context is null because at the time when you pass it to the DBHelper constructor it hasn't been instantiated yet. Move the DBHelper instantiation into the constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

because your `mContext` is `null`

place this line inside constructor..or any of your other preferece methods before using it

```
dbHelp = new DbHelper(context);
```

Comment: `dbHelper` is not `null` but otherwise this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
Context mContext;

private SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper dbHelp = new DbHelper(mContext);
```

The `mContext` you passed to `DbHelper` constructor is `null`.

You should not initialize any class member requiring a valid `Context` until `onCreate()` anyway.